# Unable to select CUDA or OptiX with new 3090, "No compatible GPUs found" message

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Unable to select CUDA or OptiX with new 3090, "No compatible GPUs found" message

I just upgraded from a Vega 64, installed 3090 card (Gigabyte Vision OC), installed latest drivers (tried both game and studio) and nothing.

I can only choose CPU rendering.

OpenCL is obviously now disabled, yet I get the  "No compatible GPUs found" for CUDA and Optix as well.

Comment: Try updating to the latest drivers and the latest version of blender.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm already on the latest Nvidia drivers (460.89) and was trying the latest builds (both stable and experimental) of Blender with still no joy...

Comment: Sometimes downgrading the drivers works... but it is also possible that the hardware is too new and not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters the same problem:

I reinstalled my windows (keeping apps and files) and suddenly it was recognised in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating, but usually a trick is to install the Studio Drivers instead of the Game Ready drivers. I had a similar issue when I bought RTX 2080 (in 2018), not related to blender (unfortunately). But before you go again for a clean format give a chance to the Studio Drivers.